# How do I get rid of the whitespace between different bootstrap classes/elements?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a beginner when it comes to website design. How do I get rid of the whitespace between my jumbotron navbar and footer?
There is whitespace between the jumbotron and the following Navbar aswell as the following footer thereafter. Attached is the following jsfiddle> https://jsfiddle.net/5c6kx9tu/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mj.css">
  <title>Michael Jordan Tribute Page</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    </div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About MJ</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Accomplishments</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Statistics</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Quotes</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
<footer class="footer container-fluid text-center">
  <p>"Website created using Bootstrap 4 by Andrew"</p>
</footer>

</body>
```

And here is the css

```
.jumbotron{
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image:url(mj.jpg);
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.footer{
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: grey;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.text-center{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: First, hopefully you are using your browser's developer's tools.  You can see _exactly_ what rules are causing those vertical spaces.  Second, once you do, you'll see that `jumbotron` and `nav` _both_ have `margin-bottom` on them.  While your CSS would resolve those issues, your CSS _must appear_ **after** the bootstrap-loaded CSS, or else have higher specificity.  **LASTLY**, I'd strongly recommend that you _not_ change the bootstrap styles directly, but instead create some helper classes - such as `mb-0: margin-bottom: 0 !important;`, and apply those _where and as needed_

Comment: As a side-note, your code says "created with bootstrap four" (which _has_ those helper classes I mentioned), but your fiddle is _loading_ bootstrap 3.  Which one do you want to use?

Answer (score 1):

I'd *strongly* recommend not modifying core bootstrap styles, but rather utilizing some helper classes.

If you're using Bootstrap 3 (which you are loading in your code), you'll need to write some helper classes, like I've done in this fiddle, and below:

CSS helper classes (you can add other - mt (for margin top), 5em (for .5 em), etc:

```
/* helper class, modeled after Bootstrap 4 helper classes */
.mb-0 {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Then simply add those classes to your markup, like below:

```
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron mb-0">
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default mb-0">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About MJ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Accomplishments</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Statistics</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Quotes</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <footer class="footer container-fluid text-center">
      <p>"Website created using Bootstrap 4 by Andrew"</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
```

Working example / fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/0gn7w3Lk/1/

If you're using Bootstrap 4, those helper classes already exist, and you can use them: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/

Comment: .mb-0 {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}Why would you change the margin, shouldnt you change the padding?

Comment: or did you just use that as an example?

Comment: Because the fiddle had margin issues.  If desired, you can build the same utility classes for padding.

Comment: how so? what were the issues?

Answer (score 0):

If you add

```
.navbar {
margin: 0;
}
```

That should clear it up. Play around with that.
Make sure you add that somewhere AFTER your include of the bootstrap style sheet, so it overrides the bootstrap css.

Comment: Can you hard refresh to make sure? It's working on my end. For sure the .navbar selector has a margin-bottom of 20px, you could target that specifically

Comment: Also as I said... make sure style modification comes LOWER somewhere on the page below where you call the bootstrap file. Link to the bootstrap css and then link to your custom css below that, for example.

Comment: "style modification comes LOWER somewhere" explain please I am new

Comment: Could I have replaced .navbar with nav ? or navbar navbar-default?

Comment: You need each of those styles, nav and navbar do their own specific things. And I believe navbar-default sets the color to that gray.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the whitespace between jumbotron and navbar, all you need to do is calling your stylesheet below the bootstrap stylesheet. And then, in your stylesheet, you need the following lines to remove the whitespace between navbar and footer:

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's better not to change bootstrap own classes, make your owns classes or id's instead.

Also keep in mind where you are going to add css, it's better add css after bootstrap otherwise you could change bootstrap logic. This means you could generate unwanted behaviors.

Here just an example adding id's: https://jsfiddle.net/5c6kx9tu/5/

```
#myJumbotron{
  margin-bottom:0px;
  background-color: red;//this color it's just to see the problem clear
}

#myNavbar{
  background-color: green;//this color it's just to see the problem clear
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

The best solution then, in my opinion, is to make another file included after bootstrap and make your own classes for the elements that you want to change.